# Class 'OAuth' not found on apache2 on ubuntu 16.04 running php 7.0

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, oauth

I'm trying to install oauth on Ubuntu 16.04 server running apache2 and php7.0.

Can some kind soul please provide steps on how to install this on fresh Ubuntu install? I've tried everything I can find using SO and Google but can't find working solution for the combination above.

You'd think it was fairly straightforward... :-/

Comment: where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I don't know what you have tried so far and where you were stucked!! 
Anyway try below simple 3 steps..

Step 1: Update system

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 2: Install: php-oauth

After updating your system, run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php-oauth
```

Step 3: Again update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this helps for you!!